# Show user with matching app_id from URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters, controller

I want to show a user based on the `app_id` parameter given in the URL.

I want to give someone a link like  'http://localhost:3000/users/76876876876868'  and show the user with that `app_id` ("76876876876868").

I'm looking for a magicalMethod or something else that can help me accomplish this.

So this is what I have in my routes.rb:

```
  get 'users/:app_id' => 'users#show'
```

And this is what I have in my users_controller.rb:

```
  def show
     @user = User.magicalMethod(params[:app_id])
  end
```

I tried several options like `User.find(params[:app_id])` but the 'find' method works for the 'id' param.

I also tried:

```
def show
  @user = User.where(app_id: 76876876876868)
end
```

Which seems to work but I want something more dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
@user = User.where(app_id: params[:app_id])
```

If you only need one user, try this instead

```
@user = User.find_by(app_id: params[:app_id])
```

or

```
@user = User.where(app_id: params[:app_id]).first
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer :):):):)

Comment: the first answer you  gave me worked but the other two give me this error `NoMethodError in Users#show`

Comment: you are using Rails 4, right? It should have [find_by](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find_by)

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
@user = User.find_by_app_id(params[:app_id])
```

Or:

```
@user = User.find_by(app_id: params[:app_id])
```

Comment: Actually, `find_by_app_id` is deprecated